# Multipart upload with "If-Match" eTag in header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file using multipart upload. My requirement is that it should upload only if the object in AWS S3 has the same ETag I have in my cache so as to avoid accidental overwrites by the "last write wins" behavior. My code is in C# with ASP.NET Core. This is what I have tried:

using `TransferUtility`:

```
public static async Task UploadFiles(string folder)
{
    try
    {
        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (var file in allFiles)
        {
            using var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = "test",
                Key = Path.GetFileName(file),
                InputStream = fs,
                AutoCloseStream = false,
                PartSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024,
               
            };
            request.Headers["If-Match"] = ETag;
            _transferUtility.Upload(request);
            ETag = await GetEtag();
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {file}");
        }
        
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception:{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Here I see that upload succeeds even if Etag is different than the one I specified in ETag header.

I also tried using lower level APIs:

```
public static async Task UploadFiles_Raw(string folder)
{
    try
    {
        var chunkSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        var parts = new List<PartETag>();
        var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach (var file in allFiles)
        {
            var key = Path.GetFileName(file);
            using var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var resp = await _client.InitiateMultipartUploadAsync("test", key);
            while(true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                var readCount = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                UploadPartRequest uploadPartRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = "test",
                    UploadId = resp.UploadId,
                    Key = key,
                    PartNumber = parts.Count + 1,
                    PartSize = readCount,
                    InputStream = new MemoryStream(buffer),
                    IsLastPart = (readCount < chunkSize)
                };

                var uploadResp = await _client.UploadPartAsync(uploadPartRequest);
                var partETag = new PartETag(uploadResp.PartNumber, uploadResp.ETag);
                parts.Add(partETag);
                if (readCount < chunkSize)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            var completeMultipartUploadRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
            {
                BucketName = "test",
                Key = key,
                PartETags = parts,
                UploadId = resp.UploadId
            };
            await _client.CompleteMultipartUploadAsync(completeMultipartUploadRequest);
            ETag = await GetEtag();
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {file}");
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception:{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Here I was hoping that while creating `CompleteMultipartRequest` I can set the `If-Match` header with Etag. But I dont see any method to set this. What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: The comparison with the stored ETag uses the strong comparison algorithm, meaning two files are considered identical byte by byte only. If a listed ETag has the W/ prefix indicating a weak entity tag, this comparison algorithm will never match it.

Comment: I am trying to do this to avoid accidental overwrites when two writers are working. I don't want the last one wins behaviour. Instead first one succeeds and second should get pre-condition failed exception.

Comment: You can find the ETag from `var resp = await _client.GetObjectMetadataAsync("test", key);`. resp.ETag is your want.